# How to user the MatrixWidget from matrix_dart_sdk in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, matrix-org

Description:

I'm currently working on a Flutter project where I need to integrate Matrix functionality using the `matrix_dart_sdk`. I came across the `MatrixWidget` within the SDK, but I'm unsure of how to effectively use it within my Flutter application.

Here's the constructor for the `MatrixWidget`:

```dart
MatrixWidget({
  required this.room,
  this.creatorUserId,
  this.data = const {},
  this.id,
  required this.name,
  required this.type,
  required this.url,
  this.waitForIframeLoad = false,
});
```

When I try to add this widget in column or row, it says MatrixWidget it not a subtype of 'widget'.

Could someone provide guidance on how to utilize the `MatrixWidget` effectively in my Flutter application? Any code examples or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please update the question with the link to the package and service you are using and the code you have tried.